# How to ensure that MessageHandler delegate is completed during closing of MessageReciever?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I have a service that uses a `MessageReceiver` from `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` continuously to listen to a subscription in ServiceBus. When the service is stopped I would like to give a chance for all operations to complete before the process is killed.

This is the code I have used based on the [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SendersReceiversWithTopics) provided by library:

```
private async Task StartReceiveLoop(IMessageReceiver receiver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var doneReceiving = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        receiver.CloseAsync();
        doneReceiving.SetResult(true);
    });

    receiver.RegisterMessageHandler(
        async (message, ct) => await HandleMessage(receiver, message),
        new MessageHandlerOptions(HandleException));

    await doneReceiving.Task;
}
```

On Service Stop I cancel the task and the service is killed immediately even though `HandleMessage` is still running.

Is there any way that I can check via the library itself that the operation is still running to delay task cancellation? I can think of a way of doing my own counting with a lock of all the tasks that are running, but I hope there is a better way that will allow me to know the number of running handlers.

Ideally I want to unregister the Handler so that the message pump stops, while the receiver itself is not closed to allow e.g. CompleteAsync calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer suggests that it is unfortunately not possible to achieve now and the feature is quite sought after even though it's not available in the library itself. One alternative is to create your own receiving message pump, but then you are on your own with disconnect, management, etc. though graceful shutdown itself is not hard to do. With the current approach I managed to write a workaround that seems to work fine even though it is clumsy.

```
private async Task StartReceiveLoop(IMessageReceiver receiver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int activeMessageHandlersCount = 0;
    var doneReceiving = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        lock (receiver)
        {
            int attemptCount = 0;
            while (attemptCount++ < 10 && activeMessageHandlersCount > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            receiver.CloseAsync();
        }

        doneReceiving.SetResult(true);
    });

    receiver.RegisterMessageHandler(
        async (message, ct) =>
        {
            bool canBeProcessed;
            lock (receiver)
            {
                canBeProcessed = !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
                if (canBeProcessed)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref activeMessageHandlersCount);
                }
            }

            if (canBeProcessed)
            {
                try
                {
                    await HandleMessage(receiver, message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref activeMessageHandlersCount);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000); // Otherwise message receiver will keep pumping message during graceful shutdown
            }
        }, new MessageHandlerOptions(HandleException));

    await doneReceiving.Task;
}
```

One additional drawback is that Receiver will take a number of messages without processing and just keep them until lock expiration.

Answer (score 3):

As [MessageReceiver.CloseAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.cliententity.closeasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_ClientEntity_CloseAsync) mentioned as follows:

> Closes the Client. Closes the connections opened by it.

Per my testing, after called `MessageReceiver.CloseAsync()`, the subsequent invocation `CompleteAsync`,`DeadLetterAsync` would fail since the instance of `IMessageReceiver` has been disposed. If you still want to complete your queue message, you need to create a new `MessageReceiver`.

> Is there any way that I can check via the library itself that the operation is still running to delay task cancellation?

AFAIK, the SDK does not provide the above feature currently. Moreover, here is a similar [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/4345733-provide-gracefull-shutdown-feature-to-message-pump) about gracefully shutdown to message pump of Azure Service Bus.

> When the service is stopped I would like to give a chance for all operations to complete before the process is killed.

For your requirement, I assume that you need to implement it by yourself to make sure the received queue messages could be successfully handled even after the MessageReceiver has been closed. Or you could just pass `CancellationToken` parameter into your `HandleMessage` method for explicitly cancellation instead of completing retrieved messages.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work this way. I have already tried a new MessageReceiver that would act as a a "double", but it throws an exception that a message was received on another message receiver, so it does not work this way.

Comment: Cancellation I can pass, but there are some operations that are irreversible, like e.g. sending an SMS or whatever, so there is just no turning back. I ended up implementing by own counter and a shutdown loop that is similar to what was written in feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway, it seems that the feedback you have referenced to is exactly what I would like to have. It's a pity it's not implemented after 5 years after it has been posted...